# Send more than 25000 newsletter smtp

Tags: linux, email, smtp

I have newsletter that has to  send more than 25k emails.
I wanna buy a dedicated server for it ,  but i can't understand the process .

How the system works ?

How not to appear  in black list?

What software I need for it?

What I need to google :), because I can't find any info for it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try getting someone else to take care of this for you. It's a world of pain you may not want to become involved in.

We use [SendGrid](http://sendgrid.com/) at work, and it works very well. Other popular services are [AWeber](http://aweber.com/) and [MailChimp](http://mailchimp.com/).